# How can i solve [Vue warn]: Error in data(): "ReferenceError: total is not defined" in Laravel Vue

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I think my problem was in definition of profitDetails in data method.
I have already defined as follows,

```
data(){
   return{
       profitDetails:[],  
         }
      }
```

My axio i created as follw

```
getProfit(){
     axios.get('api/get-profit').then(response => {
     this.profitDetails = response.data;
     console.log('*************',response.data);
     });
 }
```

using console.log('*************',response.data) printed followings,

[image: consol log]

Using above axio i access data as follows and already printed that values but it provide console error like i attached image in bellow,

```
{{profitDetails[0].total}} 
{{profitDetails[1].total}} 
{{profitDetails[2].total}} 
{{profitDetails[3].total}}
```

but in console in shows following error
[image: error in console log]

Comment: you define `profitDetails` as an empty array. add the code were you populate it with data

Comment: i have updated the question

Comment: can you add to your question the result of console.log(response.data) in your getResponse() method

Comment: okay, i added console.log output in question

Comment: @IgorMoraru how can i solve this error

Comment: sorry my friend, I can't see any more issues in the code you provided.

Comment: What are the errors friend how can i solve that problems

Comment: I got the error like you now ;(

Answer (score 1):

You should check if profitDetails has been populated from API before rendering the template. For ex.:

```
<div v-if="profitDetails.length > 0">

{{profitDetails[0].total}} 
{{profitDetails[1].total}} 
{{profitDetails[2].total}} 
{{profitDetails[3].total}} 

</div>
```

Comment: I have tries using v-if by checking length but it was not solve

Comment: i think problem was in profitDetails definition in data method